# SAML2.0 Access token using 'itfoxtec-identity-saml2'

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to use your Nuget package for dotnet core and I get little bit success also I can login to SAML identity providers like Onelogin,Okta and I got loggin user information also But I am confuse while generating access token(Bearer token to call APIs of SAML identity providers). How will I get that token?
I can see securitytoken object in saml2AuthnResponse but don’t know how to that token and in that object security key and singin key is null.

I am totally new to this so may be I misunderstand something.

Please help me.

```
[Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
    {       
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config); 

        binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
        }
        binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal)); 
        var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
        var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to the SAML 2.0 token as a XML string by setting `Saml2Configuration.SaveBootstrapContext = true` in appsettings.json:

```
...
"Saml2": {
  "SaveBootstrapContext": true,
  "IdPMetadata": "https://localhost:44305/metadata",
  "Issuer": "itfoxtec-testwebappcore",
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you can set the configuration in code:

```
config.SaveBootstrapContext = true;
```

Then you can read the SAML 2.0 token as a XML string in the `saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.BootstrapContext`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
{       
    var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
    var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

    binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
    if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
    }
    binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
    await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));

    var samlTokenXml = saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.BootstrapContext as string;

    var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
    var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: HI, We already got this in other methods, but i want to know how we will be able to access APIs of different providers using that samlTokenXml or do we need bearer token for that?

Comment: You can probably only use the SAML 2.0 bearer token in the samlTokenXml for the applications own API. You probably need to exchange the SAML 2.0 bearer token you got using WS-Trust Act As. .NET support this but it is not part of the ITfoxtec Identity SAML component. Alternatively, you can call the providers API from your API as a trusted subsystem.